# Getting Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string just trying to do a COUNT(*)

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a quickie:

I'm confused. This is my SQL:

```
select COUNT(*) as rowCnt
from fy2015View
```

It's VERY SIMPLE and yet, DOESN'T WORK!

This is the ERROR I get:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

NO MATTER WHAT I DO, it will not work.

But, if I do that same call on another table, I get the number of rows back.

Now, this fy2015View is just that: A VIEW.

Does that have anything to do with it?

Is there something I needed to do during the creation of the view or something I "shouldn't" have done?

I can't have a long discussion to keep in compliance with Stacks rules... so please a quick answer would be best.

Comment: Obviously the problem lays with your view definition. You are attempting an invalid type conversion somewhere in your view,

Comment: You sure there isnt some other code above or below that? That code shouldn't produce an error unless the view itself has an error in it. Can you select * from the view? Remember your view will "compile" with conversion errors

Comment: As Vahid said, a view can be defined as any SELECT statement, including conversions and function calls, so long as its valid DDL at view creation time. That doesnt mean that at run time, the data is valid for the expected calls --- ie: if a field is being cast as a date in the view script, its valid to create the view, but at run time (SELECT execution) it will fail for data that is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, the issue lies in the view's definition. 
Without knowing how that view is defined, we can't give you a simple answer, and the reason why COUNT(*) fails, is because the number of records of a view that runs into execution errors is undefined.

I created a [sample sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0bf5b5/1) to show why this would occur.

Comment: Jake, you are correct and it was driving me NUTS!  The problem was that after importing over 1/2 MIL records, the "DATE" field(s), as there are 5, had "BAD" data... This was HAND JAMMED at one point and people entered: 14/05/2016 when it should've been 05/14/2016 thus, rendering the data INVALID as you so plainly put in your "Fiddle".  There's a LOT of data cleansing that needs to be completed and with over 1/2 MIL records, that takes HOURS.